# data change puts object last in query django

Tags: django, django-models

all. I encountered a weird quirk with my Django setup. Each time I make a change in a data entry at Django's admin page, the data entry becomes dead last in a Query (e.g. `Object.objects.all()`). The behavior isn't a server-threatening bug, but I'd still like to know how I could resolve the problem.

The one solution I can think of is creating a `DateField` and arranging the query by date, but I was wondering if a superior method is available.

Comment: There is no _default_ ordering as far as RDBCs are concerned and there are no guarantees that the same query will always return the rows in the same order unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause. If you are really concerned about the ordering of your objects you should define your `ordering` in the `Meta` class. You can either use a special ordering column or simply use your pk (generally `id`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. As Seluck said in comments, the `order_by` clause gets me a set order via a parameter (e.g. `-pk`).